# How to get data in enum from database instant of stastically typed data? in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, enums

Dept.cs

```
public enum Dept
{
    None,
    HR,
    IT,
    Payroll
}
```

above Dept enum data is already typed but want fetch data from database in this enum using asp.net core mvc

Model Department.cs

```
public class Department
{
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly with this Enum ? Do you want to get a specific Department type even if it's name change? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the value of an `enum` member. Enums are, by definition, groups of constants - which means that the values of their members is set at compile time and can't be changed.

From the [Enumeration types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) page on Microsoft Docs:

> An enumeration type (or enum type) is a value type defined by a set of named constants of the underlying integral numeric type.

This is why using Database data as enums is a bad idea - once the database data has changed, you'll need to change your code as well, recompile and redistribute it.